# How to import siblings so python can run both the file and downstread scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, relative-path

I'm not sure how to sort out my `import` statements in the following situation:

```
main.py
folder/
      __init__.py
      a.py
      b.py
```

`a.py`:

```py
class Base(object):
    pass
```

`b.py`:

```py
from a import Base  # If I do this, `python main.py` fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'"
from .a import Base # But if I do this, `python b.py` or `python folder/b.py` fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.a'; '__main__' is not a package"

class Kid(Base):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Toy around with Kid (informal test, debug, snippets, etc.)
    k = Kid()
```

`main.py`:

```py
from folder.b import Kid
# Main script with Kid.
k = Kid()
```

I sometimes want to run `main.py` because it's my main program.
But I sometimes want to run `b.py` because it's simpler and it contains small snippets and examples to toy around with my class `Kid` while the file is open.

I think it is legitimate to want both or there would be no point to the common construct `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

What's the right import for `b.py`? Is there a neat way I can enjoy the best of both options?

Answer (score 1):

Python imports can get ridiculous and wanting to use a module in multiple ways gets sticky. Easiest way is just try/catch it

```
try:
    from a import Base
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from .a import Base
```

Comment: That's ridiculous indeed X) But thank you. I'll wait a bit before I accept this solution because I still want to believe there is a better way ;)

Comment: I want to believe as well. I've dealt with these issues a lot lately dealing with AWS lambda's and separate test files. Hopefully someone can provide a cleaner way.

Comment: BTW, I though the very purpose of `if __name__ == '__main__':` was precisely to "use a module in multiple ways"? õ.Ô